# Java vs SQL when fetching data

Tags: java, sql

I have a table where I have saved some parameters which act as logic for deciding which "receiver" to choose. I have illustrated the content / data of this table below:

[image: table content]

For selecting the correct receiver I used the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOfReceivers
WHERE client = 'DU'
      AND (country = countryOfDestination OR '*' = countryOfDestination)
      AND (
        (packages >= minNumberOfPackages OR minNumberOfPackages IS NULL) AND
        (packages <= maxNumberOfPackages OR maxNumberOfPackages IS NULL)
      )
      AND (
        (weight >= minNetWeight OR minNetWeight IS NULL) AND
        (weight <= maxNetWeight OR maxNetWeight IS NULL)
      )
ORDER BY priority;
```

The variables for above SQL is:

```
country = BE
packages = 5
weight = 50
```

The SQL works fine and I get the result I want. But I need to translate this into Java and when doing so I feel that it's over-complicated and I'm thinking that there has to be an easier what to do this.

Here is the Java code that I'm currently using:

```
ArrayList<tableOfReceivers > listOfReceivers = getPersistenceManager().getQueryManager().queryAll(
            tableOfReceivers.class, "this.client = ?1", "this.client", new Object[] { client }, 0);

ArrayList<tableOfReceivers> result = new ArrayList<tableOfReceivers>();

for (tableOfReceivers  rec : listOfReceivers) {
    if ((StringUtils.equals(countryOfDestination, rec.getCountryOfDestination())
            || StringUtils.equals("*", rec.getCountryOfDestination()))) {

        if (((numberOfPackages >= nvl(rec.getMinNumberOfPackages(), 0))
                || rec.getMinNumberOfPackages() == null)
                && (numberOfPackages <= nvl(rec.getMaxNumberOfPackages(),0))
                || rec.getMaxNumberOfPackages() == null) {

            if (((totalNetWeight >= nvl(rec.getMinNetWeight(),0)) || rec.getMinNetWeight() == null)
                    && (totalNetWeight <= nvl(rec.getMaxNetWeight(),0)) || rec.getMaxNetWeight() == null) {
                result.add(rec);
            }
        }
    }
}

Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<tableOfReceivers >() {

    @Override
    public int compare(tableOfReceivers  o1, tableOfReceivers  o2) {
        return o1.getPriority().compareTo(o2.getPriority());
    }
});

System.out.println("Receiver selection result is:" + "\n");
if(!result.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(result.get(0).getReceiver() + "\n");
}
```

}

```
public static Integer nvl(Integer value, Integer alternateValue) {
    if (value == null)
        return alternateValue;
    return value;
}
```

So, is there an easier and better way to fetch what I need using only Java here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you only want to use Java? SQL can use indexes and other information to more effectively query the database.

Comment: Why not use Streams in Java 8? This is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Java 8

```
List<tableOfReceivers> result = 
    listOfReceivers.stream()
                   .filter(rec -> countryOfDestination.equals(rec.getCountryOfDestination())
                                  || "*".equals(rec.getCountryOfDestination())
                   .filter(numberOfPackages >= nvl(rec.getMinNumberOfPackages(), numberOfPackages ))
                   .filter(numberOfPackages <= nvl(rec.getMaxNumberOfPackages(), numberOfPackages ))
                   .filter(totalNetWeight >= nvl(rec.getMinNetWeight(), totalNetWeight))
                   .filter(totalNetWeight <= nvl(rec.getMaxNetWeight(), totalNetWeight))
                   .sort(Comparator.comparing(rec -> rec.getPriority()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you could use a helper method like `in`

```
public static boolean in(int value, Integer min, Integer max) {
    return (min == null || min <= value) &&
           (max == null || max >= value);
}

public static boolean countryMatch(String a, String b) {
    return "*".equals(a) || "*".equals(b) || a.equals(b);
}

List<tableOfReceivers> result = 
    listOfReceivers.stream()
                   .filter(rec -> countryMatch(countryOfDestination, rec.getCountryOfDestination()))
                   .filter(rec -> in(numberOfPackages, rec.getMinNumberOfPackages(), rec.getMaxNumberOfPackages())))
                   .filter(rec -> in(totalNetWeight, rec.getMinNetWeight(), rec.getMaxNetWeight(), totalNetWeight))
                   .sort(Comparator.comparing(rec -> rec.getPriority()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the power of the Stream ! But what about the perfs ?

Comment: That's awesome and thanks for the help! I need to catch up on those streams.

Comment: @AxelH in general perf is the same as loops for warmed up code. The sorting can be a bit slower but rarely enough to matter.

Comment: @AxelH note the very first time you run the code it's a lot slower.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sorry, I meaning compared to SQL of course. Don't used a lot of these (the office still use Java 6...........) but I guess each filter call will loop once (on the resulting stream). But the SQL might be more efficient with the index (if any)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, slower for the first call on a process ? Might need to pop the hood of those then

Comment: @AxelH I would expect the SQL to be faster as you don't have to download the whole table first. Once it is downloaded it is likely to be faster in memory unless there is some clever use of indexes. Note you can add indexes in Java too.

Comment: @AxelH the first use of streams/lambdas can be 10x longer of more than a loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I will stop the spam here ;) I will check about it, this seems really well made. I hope they will think about upgrading Java one day at the office... Thanks for the info !

Comment: @AxelH one of the cool features of the Stream API is you can use `parallelStream()` and it will use all the CPUs of your machine (possibly without changing any other code)